# Selenium: Chrome and contextMenu item pressing

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, contextmenu

I want to test pasting from context menu in different browsers.

I use `new Actions(driver).contextClick(element).perform();` for calling the context menu and it's okay for Firefox and Chrome.

In Firefox for selecting menu item I'm using `driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("p");` and it's also goes fine.

But I don't know a way how to do this in Chrome: each time I'm trying to type something from driver's keyboard text appears int the text field (on which context menu was called).

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug regarding the simulation mechanism of context switch.
In Chromedriver 2.2 this problem is solved.
If you want to learn more about this issue, [check this link](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=410).
In older version of chromedriver,  try to simulate the context menu event via JavaScript.